# postgresql - column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. But I don't want to do either of those things

Tags: postgresql

```
select res.*, (res.revision_rank - min(revision_rank)) as blah from
(
select distinct branch, test_type, test_suite, test_plan, test_case, build_age, passed, failed, test_count, min_in_case, revision, has_case_comment::int, has_plan_comment::int, has_suite_comment::int, has_type_comment::int, test_job, initialreport, revision_rank from 
 (select *, MIN(passed) OVER (PARTITION BY branch, test_type, test_suite, test_plan) as min_in_case 
  FROM test_result_by_case_with_comment
  WHERE branch = 'branch' AND REVISION <= 12345 AND (newest_build OR NOT true)) as b1 WHERE min_in_case = 0 OR NOT true
                                                                                        ) as res;
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "res.branch" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select res.*, (res.revision_rank - min(revision_rank)) as bl...
```

But this does not seem acceptable. What I need is each row, plus an additional column for each row showing the difference between that row's revision_rank and the absolute minimum revision_rank.

I need the absolute minimum, not a minimum over a partition or within a group. Is it possible to do what I need here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query (a bit simplified):

```
select i, sum(i)
from generate_series(1, 3) g(i);

ERROR:  column "g.i" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select i, sum(i)
```

You can use the aggregate as a window function:

```
select i, sum(i) over ()
from generate_series(1, 3) g(i);

 i | sum 
---+-----
 1 |   6
 2 |   6
 3 |   6
(3 rows)
```

or calculate the aggregate in a separate query:

```
with query as (
    select i
    from generate_series(1, 3) g(i)
    ),
summary as (
    select sum(i)
    from query
)
select *
from query
cross join summary
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can work:

```
WITH temp as (SELECT MIN(revision_rank) as absmin FROM test_result_by_case_with_comment)

    select res.*, (res.revision_rank - temp.absmin) as blah from
    (
    select distinct branch, test_type, test_suite, test_plan, test_case, build_age, passed, failed, test_count, min_in_case, revision, has_case_comment::int, has_plan_comment::int, has_suite_comment::int, has_type_comment::int, test_job, initialreport, revision_rank from 
     (select *, MIN(passed) OVER (PARTITION BY branch, test_type, test_suite, test_plan) as min_in_case 
      FROM test_result_by_case_with_comment
      WHERE branch = 'branch' AND REVISION <= 12345 AND (newest_build OR NOT true)) as b1 WHERE min_in_case = 0 OR NOT true) as res, temp
```

The idea is to just calculate the abs minimum first and then use it wherever you need it. Note the inclusion of temp in the implicit join.